# Issues with async if statement calculating final value using promises from Discord.JS library api

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am having trouble I believe that is due to async. Here is the code:

```js
const calculateMessageKarma = async (reaction) => {
  if (reaction.partial) {await reaction.fetch();}
  // Get The Member That Gave Karma & Verify Author = Karma Giver
  let mK = 0; let tMK = 0;
  //Upvotes
  if(await reaction.message.reactions.resolve(config.reactions.UPVOTE)){
    let uvotes = await reaction.message.reactions.resolve(config.reactions.UPVOTE).users.fetch()
    await uvotes.forEach(async vote => {
      let member = await reaction.client.guilds.cache.find((guild) => guild.id === config.guilds.zentrading).members.fetch(vote.id).then((value) => { return value; });
      if(vote.id === reaction.message.author.id) return; // Dont count reactions to own messages
      if (member.roles.highest.id == config.roles.guildlead.id) { mK += 5}
      else if (member.roles.highest.id == config.roles.guildmod.id) { mK += 4;}
      else if (member.roles.highest.id == config.roles.arahant.id) {mK += 3}
      else if (member.roles.highest.id == config.roles.non_returner.id) {mK += 2}
      else if (member.roles.highest.id == config.roles.once_returner.id) { mK += 1}
      else if (member.roles.highest.id == config.roles.non_returner.id) {mK += 1}
      else {mK += 0}
    })
  }
  //Downvotes
  if(await reaction.message.reactions.resolve(config.reactions.DOWNVOTE)){
    let dvotes = await reaction.message.reactions.resolve(config.reactions.DOWNVOTE).users.fetch()
    await dvotes.forEach(async vote => {
      let member = await reaction.client.guilds.cache.find((guild) => guild.id === config.guilds.zentrading).members.fetch(vote.id).then((value) => { return value; });
      if(vote.id === reaction.message.author.id) return; // Dont count reactions to own messages
      if (member.roles.highest.id == config.roles.guildlead.id) { mK += -5}
      else if (member.roles.highest.id == config.roles.guildmod.id) { mK += -4;}
      else if (member.roles.highest.id == config.roles.arahant.id) {mK += -3}
      else if (member.roles.highest.id == config.roles.non_returner.id) {mK += -2}
      else if (member.roles.highest.id == config.roles.once_returner.id) { mK += -1}
      else if (member.roles.highest.id == config.roles.non_returner.id) {mK += -1}
      else {mK += 0}
    })
  }
  if (mK > 0) { tMK = 2 + Math.floor(mK / 10) * 1;} 
  else if (mK < 0){ tMK = -1 + Math.floor(mK / 5) * -1;} 
  else { tMK = 0;}
  return tMK;
}
```

This is meant to count the number of two different reactions and assign weight of these reactions based on the members role and then take the value mK and calculate a score for the message based on a formula. The code works fine for `config.reactions.UPVOTE` but the `config.reactions.DOWNVOTE` if statement is almost being ignored. I have debugged and determined that the if statements are being evaluated but its not returning the proper calculation.

As well I know the ID's are correct as when messageReactionAdded and messageReactionRemove is called, it is checking the reaction before calling this function.

Node Version: 16.4.0

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a solution by using the following:

As part of the documentation:
`await reaction.message.reactions.resolve(config.reactions.DOWNVOTE).users.fetch()`

> Resolves with a collection of users, mapped by their ids.

[image]

Therefore we need to use `.values()` to return a map that we can iterate using something like this:

```
let votes = await reaction.message.reactions.resolve(config.reactions.DOWNVOTE).users.fetch().then(users => {return users.values()})
    for(vote of votes){
```

This for loop now properly returns the values necessary to calculate mK.